# How to get customer details in checkout_onepage_controller_success_action observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, fatal-error

I am creating an observer where I want to change group id of customer after placing an order.

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCustomerId() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\Vendor\MyModule\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupAfterOrder.php
>   on line 30

`events.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="persistence_one" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupAfterOrder"  />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here is my `observer/ChangeCustomerGroupAfterOrder.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;



class ChangeCustomerGroupAfterOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID = 1;
    protected $_logger;
    protected $customer;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
         \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->customer =$customer;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

        }
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $customers = $this->customer->load($customerId);
        $name = $customers->getName(); //customer name
        $groupid = $customers->getGroupId();
        $this->_logger->addDebug(' Customer ID: ' . $customerId . ', Customer Name: ' . $name . ', GroupId:' . $groupid);

        $this->logger->debug(' SUPRIYA AfterOrder Observer Is called!' . $customers->getFirstname());
        if ($customers->getGroupId() == 7) {
            $customers->setGroupId(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID);
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customers);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` only dispatches the last order id:

```
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
        ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
    );
```

So you'll have to load the order first in order to get the customer id. Replace this code:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

With:

```
$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
$order = $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->get($orderId);
```

Then update your constructor with:

```
protected $_orderRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
     \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepositoryInterface
) {
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_orderRepositoryInterface = $orderRepositoryInterface;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->customer =$customer;
}
```

### Suggestion

Do not load the customer using the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` model and use service contract instead. You are already using the repository interface in your constructor so you only need to remove those lines:

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
```

And:

```
$this->customer =$customer;
```

And:

```
protected $customer;
```

Finally, you can replace:

```
$customers = $this->customer->load($customerId);
```

With:

```
$customers = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
```

Comment: $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
        ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
    );                                                                                                                                                                                 where to use this??

Comment: @supriyamishra yes that's original code from Magento core you don't need to add that to your observer, it's just to show you how the event is dispatched

Comment: Okay m trying updated one

Comment: am getting this error : Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\OrderRepository.php on line 79
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\OrderRepository.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Illegal offset ...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 79, Array)

Comment: @supriyamishra no idea, try debugging to see what's happening at this line

Comment: How can I load customer group Id from Order id in Execute function?

Comment: @supriyamishra well the same way I've done it. Update your code with the code I gave you

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

you can get customer data in after save event if you have passed it from dispatched event.