# how to get customer group id from last order id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to change customer group after placing an order so I need Customer Group id which can be update in observer . How to achieve it?

Comment: last order of current customer?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144164/how-to-get-customer-details-in-checkout-onepage-controller-success-action-observ/144171#144171    here i want to do the same

Answer (score 1):

**If you have Order object then you can that customer group by**

> ```
> $order->getCustomerGroupId();
> ```

**If want to change it the use**

> ```
>  $order->setCustomerGroupId('New_Your_Group_id');
>  $order->_getResource()->saveAttribute($order, 'customer_group_id');
> ```

Comment: how I can update there this customer group id ?

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism, give u right answer.. you need to implemet that properly